# Relation between Weierstrass $ \wp $ function and elliptic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I want to see how the Weierstrass $ \wp $ function and its derivative can define the curve
$$ y ^ 2 = 4x^3 - g_2 x - g_3 $$
I think I can simulate the $ \wp $ function and its derivative properly, but I don't understand how could they define the curve mentioned above. If I make $x:=\wp(z)$ and $y:=\wp'(z)$ what do I do when $\wp(z)$ is not real? Here is the link to my worksheet: https://www.geogebra.org/m/eydcwzzt
As you can see I am not a master of this topic, but I am very interested and I want to understand these relations.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).